# Not include this specific date in the query when using BETWEEN operator in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2008, filter, between

There is one specific date that I do not want to include in this which is "04/08/2020". I want to filter all the records from the beginning of the year till now but not 04/08/2020. How can I do that?

```
SELECT 
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.PTIDNum,
     rtrim(acp.LastName) + ', ' + rtrim(acp.FirstName) AS Name,
     acp.BadgeID AS ID,
     dbo.Patient.PcFLD01 as Organization,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.Risk AS Exposure, 
     UPPER(dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.Type) AS Mask_Type,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.OHSNotes AS Comments,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.MedicallyClearedDate AS Medically_Cleared,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.TrainingCompletedDate, 
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.DateIssued AS N95_Fittest_Completed, 
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.Mask AS N95_respirator,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.PAPR,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.PaprFitTestDate AS PAPR_Fittest_Completed,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.Active,
     DATEADD(year, 1, dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.MedicallyClearedDate) AS Compliant_Through
FROM       dbo.PID_RespiratorFit LEFT JOIN 
           dbo.Patient ON dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.PTIDNum = dbo.Patient.PTIDNUM LEFT JOIN
           dbo.aspnet_CustomProfile acp ON dbo.Patient.PGuid = acp.UserId
WHERE (dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.DateIssued BETWEEN '1-1-2020' AND Getdate())
```

[image: test]

Comment: Just use the between operator for your range and a separate `and <> bad_date `

Comment: I tried that and <> date but it still showing the date 04/08/2020 :(

Comment: We need to see more of your query where it does that..

Comment: just updated full query

Comment: That query does not attempt to filter any specific date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard date formats!  Then:

```
WHERE dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.DateIssued BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND Getdate() and
      dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.DateIssued <> '2020-04-08'  -- or is that 2020-08-04???
```

If the date is really a date/time, then use:

```
WHERE dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.DateIssued BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND Getdate() and
      CONVERT(DATE, dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.DateIssued) <> '2020-04-08'  -- or is that 2020-08-04???
```

I also strongly recommend table aliases so the query is much easier to write and read.  For example:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM dbo.PID_RespiratorFit rf LEFT JOIN 
     dbo.Patient p
     ON rf.PTIDNum = p.PTIDNUM LEFT JOIN
     dbo.aspnet_CustomProfile acp
     ON p.PGuid = acp.UserId
    WHERE rf.DateIssued BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND Getdate() AND
          CONVERT(DATE, rf.DateIssued) <> '2020-04-08'  -- or is that 2020-08-04???
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below - adding an extra condition

```
    SELECT 
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.PTIDNum,
     rtrim(acp.LastName) + ', ' + rtrim(acp.FirstName) AS Name,
     acp.BadgeID AS ID,
     dbo.Patient.PcFLD01 as Organization,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.Risk AS Exposure, 
     UPPER(dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.Type) AS Mask_Type,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.OHSNotes AS Comments,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.MedicallyClearedDate AS Medically_Cleared,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.TrainingCompletedDate, 
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.DateIssued AS N95_Fittest_Completed, 
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.Mask AS N95_respirator,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.PAPR,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.PaprFitTestDate AS PAPR_Fittest_Completed,
     dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.Active,
     DATEADD(year, 1, dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.MedicallyClearedDate) AS Compliant_Through
FROM       dbo.PID_RespiratorFit LEFT JOIN 
           dbo.Patient ON dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.PTIDNum = dbo.Patient.PTIDNUM LEFT JOIN
           dbo.aspnet_CustomProfile acp ON dbo.Patient.PGuid = acp.UserId
WHERE (dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.DateIssued BETWEEN '1-1-2020' AND Getdate())
AND cast(dbo.PID_RespiratorFit.DateIssued as date)<>'2020-04-08'
```

Comment: I tried that and it's still showing the 04/08/2020 date

Comment: post your full query with sample data @Ph14Woozies. Then it'll be helpfull to find out why it is not working

Comment: @Ph14Woozies, I've updated the answer, you need to cast your DateTime column to date for the 2nd condition - you can chk now

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried this and its filter out the date that I wanted